# struts2 ognl retrieve data from session (nested property tags?)

Tags: struts2, ognl

I have a situation where I would like to retrieve data from the session on a jsp using OGNL. The data in my session is stored like this:

/data/abc/-Name (key)  ->  ABC Inc. (value)

I can easily retrieve this from the session by doing

```
<s:property value="#session['/data/abc/-Name']"/>
```

But unfortunately, the string '/data/abc/' is a dynamic one and is stored in my action under the variable companyFolder.

How do I use this variable to get the data from the session.. something like

```
<s:property value="#session['%{companyFolder}-Name']"/> // this didnt work
<s:property value="#session['<s:property value="%{companyFolder}"/>-Name']"/> // this didnt work
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<s:property value="#session[companyFolder + '-Name']" />
```

I would likely do this in the action, though, using `SessionAware`. This makes things easier to test, and avoids executing the JSP to see if things work.